In Gitlab, how do I enable/disable users to merge their own merge requests?
I found the setting to prevent a user from approving its own merge request. I want this setting to be active as it makes sense. However, with that setting activated, I need users to be able to merge their own merge requests once approved. I found that some users can merge their own merge requests, whereas other users, like me, have to ask someone else to merge it. I have role maintainer like the users who can merge their own merge requests. Where do I configure this ?

Is that different behavior on the same role in the same project? Different projects may have different settings.

Same project, same role maintainer

Does your project use Code Owners?

I couldn't find a CODEOWNER file, but does that mean the project doesn't use Code Owners ?

I believe that's what it would mean.
